# NavigationBar appearance() (tint color ..)

Tags: ios, swift

How can I set a tint color to a specific navigation controller ?

Because by using :

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 0.1, green: 0.22, blue: 0.212, alpha: 1)
```

The color will be set to all navigation controllers , isn't it ?

I've tried this code but it is not working ! Why ?

```
let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: feedvc)
nav.navigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 0.1, green: 0.22, blue: 0.212, alpha: 1)
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the color when the view controller appears and removing it when the view controller disappears ?

Comment: Do you mean accessing to it from the viewcontroller class ? Because I'm trying to do it from the appdelegate

Comment: check *DMan* answer please

Comment: It worked for me but I want to now why it nav.navigationBar can't access to appearance() while UINavigationBar can ? Aren't they the same type ?  @WilliamKinaan

Comment: navigation controller is not the same as navigation bar. navigation bar is the bar at the top, while navigation controller is ... well.. a specific kind of view controller

Comment: @WilliamKinaan I agree but `nav` is a `UINavigationController()` and `nav.navigationBar` is a `UINavigationBar()` So normally both `UINavigationBar()` & `nav.navigationBar` should be able to access to `.appearance()`am I wrong ?

Comment: Where do you have `UINanviagtionBar()`, you've showed UINavigationContoller, not UINavigationBar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116717/discussion-between-ramsserio-and-william-kinaan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the tint of a specific controller by accessing `barTintColor` directly:

`nav.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 0.1, green: 0.22, blue: 0.212, alpha: 1)`

Comment: It worked for me but I want to now why it `nav.navigationBar` can't access to `appearance()` while UINavigationBar can ? Aren't they the same type ?

Comment: I'm not sure if this suffices as a "why", but `appearance()` is a static method in Swift, so you can't call it on an instance of a class.

Comment: Oh yes @DMan ! You are right ! So the question now is how can I change the appearance() of a specific instance and not all the UINavigationBar appearance in the app?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly - doesn't the code above suffice? Changing the appearance of a specific instance is done by accessing the property you want to change directly - `UINavigationBar.appearance()`, on the other hand, returns an appearance proxy that changes _all_ instances once its properties are set.

Answer (score 1):

appearance() is used for changing things on a global scale and it takes effect for the *next* instance of something that is created.

So for example if you set it in the viewDidLoad of an object which is of the same type as you are applying appearance() then it is too late as that object has already been created. However in your case you are calling it on an instance not a class and so it wouldn't work anyway as it is a class method not an object method.

That is why it is not working in your code, to change the color just set `nav.navigationBar.barTintColor`.

Comment: The tintColor was just an exemple I want to change the appearance in general !
I am not using it in a ViewDidLoad but in the app delegate so what's the problem ? And how can I change the appearance of a unique instance of navigation bar ?

Comment: You can change an individual instance either in its viewDidLoad by setting its values directly as in my answer, or check out documentation and tutorials on appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses